# How to host a nuxt js SSR website on cpanel exactly on public_html folder with https and correct htaccess

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

Hello i have tried hosting a nuxt js SSR website on cpanel it worked at first using the "node js create app" at a subdomain, but now i wanted to deploy it on another server on the main folder public_html
I keep getting 503 error and 404 error
Also SSL certificate problem
I need the correct steps to follow in order to host a nuxt js app

Comment: Hi, hard to help you with just that. [ask]

Comment: I just need steps to follow in order to host a nuxt js website on cpanel , couldn't find anything online helping, on the official website there are some links for deployment , but nothing about cpanel , thanks in advance

Comment: Making a quick search gives this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454538/8816585

Comment: Thanks for the response , The problem here is i have to run a command with pm2 in the terminal of the server, i used the terminal of my cpanel, it always says npm command not found , and pm2 command not found, does doing it locally and then upload work ?

Comment: Do you have Node.js installed there? You should probably try to connect there as SSH. And either pull the Nuxt app there or directly push it there via a CI (if it's available on the platform).

Comment: Yep i already have that node js icon in the software section of cpanel, i'll try contacting the support team about it and about SSH access in order to try and push the project to the directory , i'll post an update if anything is solved , thank you so much for your time

Comment: Not sure about the icon. Can you achieve a successful SSH connection there? Like as in my linked answer (OP is using SSH on Windows)?

Comment: I couldn't access using SSH, also i did an update on my comment

Comment: You should start by accessing it with SSH. Modern, simple and efficient way to work with your server.

Comment: Sure i'll try to do that right away, i'll post an update here if it's solved , thanks again for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.