# Build error on nuxt.js on cpanel on custom project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Trying to deploy nuxt SSR site on a shared hosting over cpanel. Everything works properly until I get following error on build:

```
node :events: 368


throw er; / Unhandled 'error' event
Error: spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodej s16/root/usr/bin/node EAGAIN

at Process .ChildProcess . handie.onexit (node: internal/ child_procesS :282 : 19)
at onErrorNT (node: internal/ child process: 47/:16)
at prOcess'TiCkSAndRejections (node: internal/process/task_queues: 83:21)

Emitted "error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process .ChildProcess . handle.onexit (node: internal/child _process : 288 : 12)
at onErrorNT (node: internal/child process : 477:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node: internal/process/task_queues : 83: 21) {
   errno: -11f
   COde EAGAIN',
   syscall: 'spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodej s16/root/usr/bin/node',
   path: '/opt/alt/alt-nodej s16/root/usr/bin/node',
   spawnargs: I
   '/home3/grihasan/nodevenv/front/16/1ib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild. js'
```

Node version:

> 16.13.2

Tried clearing cache, reinstalling dependencies, reinstalling node. Tried lower versions as well and I'm getting same error message.

**Bare nuxt installation works perfectly though.**

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
"dev": "nuxt",
"build": "nuxt build",
"start": "nuxt start",
"generate": "nuxt generate"


},
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/http": "^0.6.4",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "nuxt-leaflet": "^0.0.27",
    "swiper": "^5.4.5",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^2.7.1",
    "vuex-map-fields": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5"
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, does it work if you build it locally?

Comment: Yeah, it does  build locally. I was wondering if it's a problem with my server not having enough resources to build. It is on shared hosting anyway and with a python app running already.

Comment: Maybe give it a try on Heroku or somewhere simple.

Comment: Yeah, its building on heroku too. Maybe, I should get a VPS.

Comment: cPanel is not that easy to setup apparently yeah. Maybe give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454538/8816585